# Static or fixed URL for Firebase storage images

Tags: image, google-cloud-firestore, ionic3, firebase-storage

My app is in Ionic 3 and images are stored in Firebase storage. To get the URL in runtime the following method needs to be used.

```
firebase.storage().ref().child(filePath).getDownloadURL();
```

This call takes a bit of time to get the URL and for the image to load.
Is there an alternative to use a static URL if I have the file name?
I have checked that the download URL looks like the following and always follow a pattern.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.com/o/folderName%fileName.jpeg?alt=media&token=tokenNumber
```

Before the `token` number, the first part is always the same if we replace the `folderName` and `fileName`.

Can we generate the token number and generate the URL faster?

**EDIT:**
An image can be uploaded and the URL can be stored in the database but its not feasible in my case. The app contains social network flow where each user will have a display pic URL and will be able to see fiend’s display pic in a list view. This will cause a lot of read if URL is to be fetched from each user's data.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the URL once, store it in a database (you tagged this with Cloud Firestore, so I'm assuming you use that) so it's easy to find when you need it.

You could also generate a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) on a backend you control.

Or you could use this Cloud Storage documentation about [public data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data) to learn about API links.

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for your response. Your you tube videos are very helpful. 
Please check my edited part in the question. 
The 1st suggestion is not effective for me for number of reads. 
Also I am  not sure whether the signed URL or public data can help in my case.

Comment: Hey, why are signed URL's or public data not useful for you? Can you give more information? Also I think that your question after the edit has converted into a much more design or use case oriented question and maybe it would be a good idea to post a new one as Doug answered your main issue.